# How do I provide type definitions for a module that uses path-based imports?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using an NPM module that requires importing React components using the following structure:

```
import Component from 'module-name/lib/components/Component';
import AnotherComponent from 'module-name/lib/components/AnotherComponent';
```

How would I go about creating a definition file that allows me to write type definitions for this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring definitions for modules such as these is the same as defining any other module:

```
declare module 'module-name/lib/components/Component' {
    import * as React from 'react';
    interface ComponentProps {
        token: string;
        language: string;
    }
    export default class Component extends React.Component<ComponentProps, any> {}
}
```

This definition can be placed in a top-level `module-name.d.ts` definition file